# How to use a model class from a module in the application bootstrap in a Zend Framework based application?

Tags: zend-framework, model, module, autoload, bootstrapping

I am developing a Zend Framework MVC application with some modules, in example, the Users module. There is a model class name "Users_Model_User" that can be used in any module/controller operation. But I need to use an instance of that model in the application Bootstrap class, but there I get an exception:

> Fatal error: Class 'Users_Model_User' not found in /my/path/...

I have a Bootstrap class for each module:

```
class Users_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {

    protected function _initAutoloader() {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => 'Users_',
                    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/users'
                ));

        return $autoloader;
    }

}
```

and as I said, the modules are working just fine (reciving requests, processing and returning responses). I think this works fine due to the module bootstrap class, that takes care of loading the default module resources, like model classes. But the main Bootstrap class seems to lack of access to the "Users" module model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try(not sure it will work)

```
protected function __initSomething()
{
   $this->bootstrap('autoload');
   $model = new Users_Model_User();
   ...
}
```

i don't think bootstrap is a good place to do mysql queries, **you should use** a `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract`, that way the resources are initiated and the bootstrap autoload is working(i'm using a plugin myself to do queries and check for permissions...)

Comment: I tried your solution, and it didn't work:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "autoload" not found' in  /my/path...

Also, my model class is not for SQL queries. It just holds a user's attribute set.

Your proposal is good too. I am going to use a plugin to setup what I need, using the User model class, that is, the current application's user.

Comment: try to change this->bootstrap('autoloader') instead of this->bootstrap('autoload') (because your function is called _initAutoloader and not _initAutoload)

Answer (score 3):

`Users_Bootstrap` is executed after your application bootstrap, which means that your `_initAutoloader()` method hasn't been executed yet in your application bootstrap.

A solution could be to move your code from `_initAutoloader()` to your main bootstrap. This will solve your problem! You could also mean the piece of code in your main bootstrap to your module bootstrap, this will even make more sense to me. Note that **all your modules bootstrap are always called**, independently to the current module requested.

Also, let me share with you [this article](http://mwop.net/blog/234-Module-Bootstraps-in-Zend-Framework-Dos-and-Donts.html) about the bootstrapping process in ZF, hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, moving the _initAutoloader() method to the main bootstrap class didn't work. I still get the "classnot found" exception. By the way, thank you for the shared article. It is very usefull.

Comment: Did you move it above the method that uses `Users_Model_User`? Ensure you have "bootstrapped" your autoloader in the bootstrap method that uses `Users_Model_User` with `$this->bootstrap('autoloader');`.